# Hide row(tr) of data table after delete via ajax in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'am trying to delete a record in **codeigniter** using **ajax** call. Delete function is working fine My issue is to hide the row after delete. i am using **bootstrap data table** in view

```
<script>
  function remove_cart(itemid) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Delete you really want to delete?");
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var btn = this;
    alert(btn);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '<?php echo site_url("admin/careers/delete/' + itemid + '")?>',
      data: {
        id: itemid
      },
      success: function(Success) {
        $(btn).closest('tr').fadeOut("fast");

      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

**View**

```
<a onclick="remove_cart('<?php echo $info['id']; ?>')" id="id">test</a>
```

**Table**

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Post applied</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Resume</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($jobs as $info) {?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $info['fname'];?> </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $info['post_applied'];?> </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $info['phone'];?> </td>
            <td><a href="http://abravmsd.com/uploads/<?php echo $info['resume'];?>" target="_blank">Download</a> </td>
            <td>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/careers/delete/<?php echo $info['id']; ?>" class="delete">Delete</a>
                <a onclick="remove_cart('<?php echo $info['id']; ?>')" id="id">test</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php  } ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: tell a liitle more about your HTML

Comment: @n4m31ess_c0d3r Thanks for your response. I have updated my question. I am using `bootstrap data table` for display my results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` might be a bit trickier inside function context. Check out [MDN documentation for `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

For your question, `remove_cart` is an inline listener and when called, `this` is set to `window` (global object).

To get the current element clicked, one of the ways could be:

```
var btn = event.target;
```

Here's a demo:

(For simplicity, I'm replacing `ajax` call with a `setTimeout` and there's hard-coded at certain places)

```js
function remove_cart(itemid) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var btn = event.target;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(btn)
      .closest("p")
      .fadeOut("fast");
  }, 100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This will be fade out after some time... <a href="" onclick="remove_cart('123')" id="id">test</a></p>
```

Another approach would be to bind the event handlers using jQuery's `.on('click')` method or js' `addEventListener` method. These are easily available on the web. Look them up!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this.

```
$(btn).closest('tr').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the deleted table row so you should add id="ID" to it for example using your info['id']:

```
foreach ($jobs as $info) { ?>
    <tr id="info_row<?= info['id'] ?>">
        <td><?php echo $info['fname'];?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $info['post_applied'];?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $info['phone'];?> </td>
        <td><a href="http://abravmsd.com/uploads/<?php echo $info['resume'];?>" target="_blank">Download</a> </td>
        <td>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/careers/delete/<?php echo $info['id']; ?>" class="delete">Delete</a>
            <a onclick="remove_cart('<?php echo $info['id']; ?>')" id="id">test</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Then change your success function in the ajax call to this:

```
$('#info_row' + itemid).fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).remove(); });
```

It uses the added table row id to fade it out and after it's hidden it will remove the row from dom.

Just a notice: You should get rid of the id="id" on the remove_cart link; there should be only one element on page with the given id. If this styles the link somehow just change it to class="id"